# Find the values from another data frame with repetitive ids using another frame with unique id in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I really stuck in this problem and dont have any idea how to solve that.
I have two data frame, one is for the humidity and its data are reported every 15 minutes. I have three different sensors for reporting. So, the table includes the id, the date, and hour of the reporting.
Here is:

```
df_h = pd.DataFrame({'id_h': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3}, 'date': {0: '2021-01-01', 1: '2021-01-01', 2: '2021-01-01', 3: '2021-01-01', 4: '2021-01-01', 5: '2021-01-01'}, 'time_hour': {0: '6:00:00', 1: '6:15:00', 2: '6:00:00', 3: '6:15:00', 4: '6:00:00', 5: '6:15:00'}, 'VALUE': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 20, 3: 22, 4: 30, 5: 32}})

   id_h        date time_hour  VALUE
0     1  2021-01-01   6:00:00     10
1     1  2021-01-01   6:15:00     12
2     2  2021-01-01   6:00:00     20
3     2  2021-01-01   6:15:00     22
4     3  2021-01-01   6:00:00     30
5     3  2021-01-01   6:15:00     32
```

with the following code, I can stick its data together and for each id, in each day, I have the humidity.

```
humidity_sticked = df_h.pivot(index=["id_h", "date"], columns="time_hour", values="VALUE")
humidity_sticked.columns = [f"value_{i+1}" for i in range(humidity_sticked.shape[1])]
humidity_sticked  =humidity_sticked.reset_index()
```

```
As we can see, we have a table with three rows and two columns.
```

Also, I have another table which shows the temperature. **But, the id for the weather center is different. For example, for id_h (id of humidity) = 1, 2 we only have the id_t (id of temperature) = 5**. So, we have exact same table for the temperature, but since the ids are different, I can not create the same stick table as humidity.
Here is the table for the temperature:

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame({'id_t': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 7}, 'date': {0: '2021-01-01', 1: '2021-01-01', 2: '2021-01-01', 3: '2021-01-01', 4: '2021-01-01'}, 'time_hour': {0: '6:00:00', 1: '6:15:00', 2: '6:00:00', 3: '6:15:00', 4: '6:00:00'}, 'VALUE': {0: -1, 1: -8, 2: -2, 3: -9, 4: -3}})

   id_t        date time_hour  VALUE
0     5  2021-01-01   6:00:00     -1
1     5  2021-01-01   6:15:00     -8
2     5  2021-01-01   6:00:00     -2
3     5  2021-01-01   6:15:00     -9
4     7  2021-01-01   6:00:00     -3
```

When I want to stick the values for id_t=5, I got an error. The desired output which I want is:
[image]

Explanation:
for id_h=1,2 we have two  5. So, for the first two rows we consider as 1, the second two rows as id=2 and the last two rows are for id=3 which are for id_t=7.

Any help can save me!Thanks

update: I've used the merge by the index, however, when I have missing values in one of the data frame, (for example for a specific date, at time 6:00 I have the humidity, but I don't have the temperature). The results are wrong.
Here is the the results of the merge by the index, we can see that the time is not same, but it put all them in one row.
[image]

Comment: just for ease of consumption; can you print out the df.head() so we can visualize the first two tables?

Comment: I think that now the table are visualized. Thanks to @bert2me for the editting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_t['rank'] = df_t.id_t.rank(method='dense')
df_h['rank'] = df_h.id_h.rank(method='dense')
df = df_t.merge(df_h, on=['rank', 'date', 'time_hour'], suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id_t        date time_hour  VALUE_1  rank  id_h  VALUE_2
0     5  2021-01-01   6:00:00       -1   1.0     1       10
1     5  2021-01-01   6:00:00       -2   1.0     1       10
2     5  2021-01-01   6:15:00       -8   1.0     1       12
3     5  2021-01-01   6:15:00       -9   1.0     1       12
4     7  2021-01-01   6:00:00       -3   2.0     2       20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pd.merge` by `index`. This way is the shortcut to make your 'sticked dataframe'.

```
pd.merge(df_t, df_h, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_t', '_h'])
```

Output:

```py
 id_t      date_t time_hour_t  VALUE_t  id_h      date_h time_hour_h  \
0     5  2021-01-01     6:00:00       -1     1  2021-01-01     6:00:00   
1     5  2021-01-01     6:15:00       -8     1  2021-01-01     6:15:00   
2     5  2021-01-01     6:00:00       -2     2  2021-01-01     6:00:00   
3     5  2021-01-01     6:15:00       -9     2  2021-01-01     6:15:00   
4     7  2021-01-01     6:00:00       -3     3  2021-01-01     6:00:00   

   VALUE_h  
0       10  
1       12  
2       20  
3       22  
4       30
```

The output above contains useless columns, so you can merge `df_t` and `df_h[only you need to merge]` like below:

```
pd.merge(df_t, df_h[['id_h','VALUE']], left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_t', '_h'])
```

Output:

```py
   id_t        date time_hour  VALUE_t  id_h  VALUE_h
0     5  2021-01-01   6:00:00       -1     1       10
1     5  2021-01-01   6:15:00       -8     1       12
2     5  2021-01-01   6:00:00       -2     2       20
3     5  2021-01-01   6:15:00       -9     2       22
4     7  2021-01-01   6:00:00       -3     3       30
```

This is the simplest way you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, when I have missing values, this method gives me a wrong results. I will update the question with the results.